# Using PyCharm to Create Multi-Language App -> Import the variables from the language file to be able to read the code

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm working on creating a multi-language app in Python using PyCharm. I've never created a multi-language app before. The app has a preference menu where the end-user can select their local language. For instance, English, Spanish, etc... If the end-user chooses English the app then uses the `languages/en.py` file.
Example of `languages/en.py`

```
welcome = 'Welcome to the app'
name_ques = 'What is your name? '
city_ques = 'What city do you live in? '
```

Example of `main.py`

```
import languages/en as lg

print(lg.welcome)
name = input(lg.name_ques)
city = input(lg.city_ques)
print(f'Your name is: {name}\nYou live in: {city}')
```

Very basic. My program is hundreds of lines long. But, as I'm writing the program it becomes increasingly hard to read the code because of the language import.
If it's been days and I come back and look at `main.py` and I see `name = input(lg.name_ques)` I have no idea what it's asking without going over to the english.py file and looking up the variable `name_ques`.

My question is, is there a way in PyCharm to have PyCharm temporarily import the "wording" so you can see what it's actually saying? If that makes any sense. I'm having a hard time explaining what I'm trying to do. PyCharm turns the `lg.name_ques` in `main.py` into `What is your name?`  temporarily while viewing the `main.py`. If that's not possible if anyone has created a multi-language app before any guidance on their procedure would greatly be appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: python in import  doesn't use `/` but `.` like `import languages.en as lg`

Comment: this problem has nothing to do with PyCharm. It all only Python problem.

Comment: you could keep translation in JSON files and load is with module `json` or use specialized modules for translations. As example - `po` files and [PoEditor](https://poedit.net/) to create them. See also [gettext](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html)

Comment: @furas You are correct! That was a typo on my part regarding your first comment. Your third comment is awesome! Thank you! I never thought about using JSON. I've done a little with PHP and I know WordPress uses PO files a lot. I'll check that out too. Thank you!

Comment: @furas I just did a little research from the information you provided and found the polib https://github.com/izimobil/polib Thank you again for the info!

Comment: For anyone else in the future; I came across an awesome article that really helps break down the process.
https://phrase.com/blog/posts/translate-python-gnu-gettext/

Comment: you could put waht you found as answer - and you can mark your answer as accepted. Few minutes later you can upvote it.

Comment: @furas Hey, thanks for the info. Will do! I'm kinda new to StackOverFlow. I've been working for the past hour on my app with the POT files. I already have half of the app translated. I created a quick API into AWS Translate. AWS Translate, translates the pot file. If it detects any changes it will send it back to AWS Translate. So cool :)  Again, thanks for the info. It really helped on this project and I'm going to use pot files on all future projects too.

Comment: as I remeber there are portals where community can help you translate it. I found only [zanata](http://zanata.org/), [loco](https://localise.biz/), [crowdin](https://crowdin.com/)

Comment: @furas Just answered the question. Again, thanks for all your help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to comments by @furas the procedure to do this is quite simple.
It's not a feature of PyCharm. Instead, the correct method is to use POT files with the GetText API.

Using the sample code in my question.
Example: `test/main.py`

```
ln = gettext.translation('base', localedir='locale', fallback=True)
ln.instal()
_ = ln.gettext
print(Welcome to the app)
name = input(_(What is your first name? ))
city = input(_(What city do you live in?))
print(f'_(Your name is: {name}\nYou live in: {city}'))
```

Anything that needs to be translated you want to add _() around it. As this is standard.
From the command prompt run:
`xgettext -i main.py -o base.pot -d base`
In your `test` directory you will now have main.py and base.pot
From the test directory: 
`mkdir -p locale/es/LC_MESSAGES`
es for whatever language. In this example Spanish.
*Note: Here is a list of 2-alpha standard language codes for GetText
[https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Usual-Language-Codes.html](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Usual-Language-Codes.htmlll)
Next copy your base.pot file into the `local/es/LC_MESSAGES` folder and rename it to .po 
`cp base.pot /test/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES/base.po`
Next is where you do the translation. Edit the `base.po` in the directory `locale/es/LC_MESSAGES` using your favorite text editor. Ex.
`nano base.po`
You will see lines starting with `msgid` and then under `msgstr ""`
Example from my sample code:

```
msgid "Welcome to the app"
msgstr ""

msgid "What is your name? "
msgstr ""

msgid "What city do you live in? "
msgstr ""
```

Use your favorite translator Ex. Google Translator or my favorite AWS Translator. *Note: AWS Translator you can upload your POT files too.
Copy your translated text from the `msgid` and copy it into the `msgstr`
Example from my code:

```
msgid "Welcome to the app"
msgstr "Bienvenido a la aplicación"

msgid "What is your name? "
msgstr "¿Cuál es su nombre? "

msgid "What city do you live in? "
msgstr "¿En qué ciudad vives? "
```

While you are editing the file in the header of the file change the line:
`Content-Type: text/plain; charset=CHARSETn`
to
`"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"` or whatever is the perferred encoding for your lanage.
Here is a reference for the heading of the .po file
https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Header-Entry.html#Header-Entry
Save your .po file
We now need to make an `.mo` file. The `.mo` file is just a binary file that is parse. To do this run the following command at the command prompt inside the `LC_MESSAGE` directory.
`msgfmt base.po -o base.mo`
Thats it! :)
From the text director where `main.py` is at you can test it out by running:
`LANGUAGE=es python3 main.py`

While learning how to do this I used this website as a reference. This is just a quick rundown. I would highly stress to take the time and read the following article as it dives deeper into using GetText.
https://phrase.com/blog/posts/translate-python-gnu-gettext/

*Side note: To use AWS Translate auto feature of the pot file here are the instructions:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/translating-your-website-or-application-automatically-with-amazon-translate-in-your-ci-cd-pipeline/